# How to access related model inside pagination (Laravel 5.1)

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5.1

```
@foreach($tasks as $t)
  {{$t->id}} // works fine
  {{$t->client->last_active}} // Trying to get property of non-object
  {{$t->client()->last_active}} // something similar error.
@endforeach
```

Given the following data structure, how could I access the `last_active` field of the related model?

[image: dump]

Task:

```
public function client(){
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Client');
}
```

Client:

```
public function tasks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Task');
}
```

Comment: Show us the related code for the `Task` and `Client` models.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be trivial, but I'll share with you anyways. One of the tasks has not been assigned to a client, so `$t->client` was null for one row. Exactly what the error message said, I just didn't believe it. :)

Through other forums I've found that `{{$t->client->last_active}}` does only work for laravel 5 and afterwards, you might need to use parantheses for earlier versions.